# UISplitViewController created in xcode 6 with ios 7 Compatibility

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller

I want to create an app which uses UISplitViewController. I am using xcode 6 + ios 8.1 SDk. I had created sample app which works fine on iOS 8 (iPhone 5 , IPhone 6+, iPad) but fails on iOS 7. Does any one help me to implement this funtionality with supporting both iOS 7 & iOS 8.(Am using Language Objective C)

Comment: carefully read UISplitViewController's class reference documentation, you should not use methods or parameters, that are avaliable only since ios 8. You can post your initilization code at least, to get concrete help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can use UISplitViewController under iOS 7 (on iPhone or iPad), but there are a few tricks. First, I'm not sure if is possible programmatically but you should use a storyboard. Second, make sure you have **Use Size Classes** checkbox option enabled on the storyboard.

Lastly, there are also some issues where you may get called with a nav controller instead of the the split view controller. For example, in the default prepareForSeque method (provided by the default split controller project), I had to make the following #if 1 tweak:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = self.objects[indexPath.row];

#if 1
        DetailViewController *controller = nil;
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            controller = (DetailViewController*)[segue.destinationViewController topViewController];
        }
        else if ([controller isKindOfClass:[UISplitViewController class]]) {
            controller = segue.destinationViewController;
        }
#else
        DetailViewController *controller = (DetailViewController*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
#endif
        [controller setDetailItem:object];
        controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
        controller.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    }
}
```